# How to support 180 degree variant for iPad in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I am designing an universal app and I like to support portrait only for both iPhone and iPad. But I need iPad to support both regular and upside down portrait orientation.

So I set Supported interface orientations for both iPhone and iPad in `info.plist` as `Portrait (top home button)` and `Portrait (bottom home button).`

Following in `AppDeleagte.swift`

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}
```

Following in `ViewController.swift`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false

    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

When I rotate my iPad upside down in simulator, it still remains upside down and does not rotate 180 degrees. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve this by doing

Following in AppDeleagte.swift

```
var shouldSupportAllOrientation = false

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
  return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portraitUpsideDown]
}
```

Following in ViewController.swift

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you had configured the Deployment Info for the project.  By default, the 'Upside Down' option is unchecked for Universal projects, and you will need to select this to get the orientation you need

[image: Xcode Deployment Info]